# How do I configure Bisna for use with Doctrine 2.1 and Zend Framework 1.11.9? [EDIT - my mistake]

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I had the previous version of Bisna (before July 22nd), with Doctrine 2.0 working good, according to the instructions in http://www.zendcasts.com/unit-testing-doctrine-2-entities/2011/02/.

Yesterday I decided to upgrade to Doctrine 2.1, and had to upgrade Bisna as well, as it was incompatible with Doctrine 2.1.
So I deleted the entire Doctrine and Bisna directories from my *library* directory, brought in the new version of each of them, added the autoload init method to the bootstrap, and updated my application.ini file with the relevant changes.

However, when I try to access the application (which worked before fine with Doctrine 2.0 and the previous version of Bisna), I get the following exception:

```
Notice: Undefined index: annotationRegistry in /home/doron/workspace/myapp/library/Bisna/Doctrine/Container.php on line 569
```

---

Advanced information:
That line (#569) is:

```
$this->startAnnotationRegistry($config['annotationRegistry']);
```

When I print the contents of `$config`, I get the following:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'annotationRegistry' => 
    array
      'annotationFiles' => 
        array
          0 => string '/home/doron/workspace/myapp/application/../library/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/DoctrineAnnotations.php' (length=103)
      'adapterClass' => string 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver' (length=44)
      'mappingNamespace' => string 'MyApp\Entity' (length=13)
      'mappingDirs' => 
    array
      0 => string '/home/doron/workspace/myapp/application/../library/MyApp/Entity' (length=65)
      'annotationReaderClass' => string 'Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader' (length=44)
      'annotationReaderCache' => string 'default' (length=7)
```

So I can see that the `annotationRegistry` property is inside an array, where the code expects it to not be inside an array.

But this is not the end, as I get the following exception as well (below the previous exception):

```
Notice: Undefined index: drivers in /home/doron/workspace/myapp/library/Bisna/Doctrine/Container.php on line 571
```

So I guess something is not configured properly, or there's a bug with Bisna.

This is my application.ini:

```
[production]

; --------------------------
; PHP Specific Configuration
; --------------------------
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
phpSettings.date.timezone = "EST"

includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
includePaths.resource = APPLICATION "/../library/Bisna/Application/Resource"

; ----------------------------------------
; Zend Framework Application Configuration
; ----------------------------------------
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"

appnamespace = "Application"

autoloaderNamespaces[] = "MyApp"
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Bisna"
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Symfony"
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Doctrine"

pluginPaths.Bisna\Application\Resource\ = "Bisna/Application/Resource"

; ------------------------------
; Front Controller Configuration
; ------------------------------
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.view[] =
resources.view.encoding = "UTF-8"
resources.view.doctype = "XHTML1_STRICT"
resources.view.contentType = "text/html; charset=UTF-8"

resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"

; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Doctrine Class Loader Configuration
; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

resources.doctrine.classLoader.loaderClass = "Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader"
resources.doctrine.classLoader.loaderFile  = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php"

resources.doctrine.classLoader.loaders.doctrine_common.namespace   = "Doctrine\Common"
resources.doctrine.classLoader.loaders.doctrine_common.includePath = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"

resources.doctrine.classLoader.loaders.doctrine_dbal.namespace   = "Doctrine\DBAL"
resources.doctrine.classLoader.loaders.doctrine_dbal.includePath = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"

resources.doctrine.classLoader.loaders.doctrine_orm.namespace   = "Doctrine\ORM"
resources.doctrine.classLoader.loaders.doctrine_orm.includePath = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"

resources.doctrine.classLoader.loaders.symfony_console.namespace   = "Symfony\Component\Console"
resources.doctrine.classLoader.loaders.symfony_console.includePath = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"

resources.doctrine.classLoader.loaders.symfony_yaml.namespace   = "Symfony\Component\Yaml"
resources.doctrine.classLoader.loaders.symfony_yaml.includePath = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"


; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Doctrine Cache Configuration
; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

; Points to default cache instance to be used. Optional is only one cache is defined
resources.doctrine.cache.defaultCacheInstance = default

; Cache Instance configuration for "default" cache
resources.doctrine.cache.instances.default.adapterClass = "Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcacheCache"
resources.doctrine.cache.instances.default.namespace    = "Application_"
resources.doctrine.cache.instances.default.options.servers.0.host = localhost
resources.doctrine.cache.instances.default.options.servers.0.port = 11211

; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Doctrine DBAL Configuration
; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

; Points to default connection to be used. Optional if only one connection is defined
resources.doctrine.dbal.defaultConnection = default

; Database configuration
;resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.parameters.wrapperClass = ""
resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.parameters.driver   = "pdo_mysql"
resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.parameters.dbname   = "myapp"
resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.parameters.host = "localhost"
resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.parameters.port = 3306
resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.parameters.user = "myapp"
resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.parameters.password = "myapp"
resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.parameters.charset = "utf-8"
resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.parameters.driverOptions.1002 = "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"


; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Doctrine ORM Configuration
; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

; Points to default EntityManager to be used. Optional if only one EntityManager is defined
resources.doctrine.orm.defaultEntityManager = default

; EntityManager configuration for "default" manager
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.connection     = default
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.proxy.autoGenerateClasses = false
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.proxy.namespace           = "MyApp\Entity\Proxy"
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.proxy.dir                 = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/MyApp/Entity/Proxy"

resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.metadataDrivers.annotationRegistry.annotationFiles[]     = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/DoctrineAnnotations.php"

resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.metadataDrivers.0.adapterClass          = "Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver"
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.metadataDrivers.0.mappingNamespace      = "MyApp\Entity"
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.metadataDrivers.0.mappingDirs[]         = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/MyApp/Entity"
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.metadataDrivers.0.annotationReaderClass = "Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader"
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.metadataDrivers.0.annotationReaderCache = default


[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
phpSettings.error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1

resources.doctrine.cache.instances.default.adapterClass = "Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache"
resources.doctrine.cache.instances.default.namespace    = "Application_"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is my mistake, I haven't noticed that the following lines:

```
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.metadataDrivers.0.adapterClass          = "Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver"
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.metadataDrivers.0.mappingNamespace      = "MyApp\Entity"
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.metadataDrivers.0.mappingDirs[]         = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/MyApp/Entity"
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.metadataDrivers.0.annotationReaderClass = "Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader"
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.metadataDrivers.0.annotationReaderCache = default
```

were renamed to

```
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.metadataDrivers.drivers.0.adapterClass          = "Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver"
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.metadataDrivers.drivers.0.mappingNamespace      = "MyApp\Entity"
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.metadataDrivers.drivers.0.mappingDirs[]         = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/MyApp/Entity"
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.metadataDrivers.drivers.0.annotationReaderClass = "Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader"
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.metadataDrivers.drivers.0.annotationReaderCache = default
```

(notice the `drivers` added before the`0`).

Answer (score 0):

FYI,
Guilherme Blanco has updated Bisna. It now works with Doctrine 2.1.0 and 2.2.0
Source:
http://phphints.wordpress.com/2011/07/10/getting-bisna-to-work-with-doctrinecommon-2-1-0/