# Zend Framework and Doctrine installation using composer

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine

I came here because I had some issue around the Doctrine ORM install.
I successfully installed the Zend Framework ([followed by these steps](https://github.com/zendframework/zendframework)) and it's works itself on my local machine.

Then I tried to install the Doctrine, ([followed by these steps](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule)) , but it's doesn't work.
[image]

When I solve that problem above, I always got an another one. I tried to check every related question in this site so far ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867198/zend-framework-2-doctrine-2)) , but it's still doesn't work.

In my .json file has `"minimum-stability": "dev",` and I tried either ZF minimal install or advanced one (with more packages).

Here is my .json file:
[image]

I have no modification here, when I try to use the `require doctrine/doctrine-orm-module:dev-master` I've got an error. Also when I typed directly into the .json file, and tried to `composer update` it.

Every answer will be appreciated!

Comment: The following two commands worked for me without any composer version conflict: `composer create-project -vvv zendframework/skeleton-application project` followed by `composer require -vvv doctrine/doctrine-orm-module`. I tend to add the `-vvv` option just to see what's going on; totally optional.

Comment: I tried, but same error message pop up:((. 
However, thanks for ur reply!

Comment: DoctrineModule currently does not support zf3

Comment: I know, but I also tried with zf2. And I've got the similar error just like above.